# Anchor tag in vertical position

Tags: html, css

Could someone assist me how we can show anchor tag vertically ?

I have anchor tag in div.

```
<div class="anchorClass">
<a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 1</a>
<a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 2</a>
<a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 3</a>
<a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 4</a>
<a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 5</a>
<a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 6</a>
<a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 7</a>
</div>
```

It is showing like this :

```
Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Test 4 Test 5 Test 6 Test 7
```

I need this in vertically align using `css`

```
Test 1 
Test 2 
Test 3 
Test 4 
Test 5 
Test 6 
Test 7
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
.anchorClass {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it , it is showing full bottom line under all anchor. Any solution for this , I have tried `display:inline-flex` but it is showing same width line. If text is lengthy then it add same anchor tag bottom line to all other anchor tag.

Comment: thats the property of anchor tag. just put ``` a { text-decoration: none;}```

Comment: okay , I will try this .If we would like to use horizontal align then what we can do with css?

Comment: @user3283738 yes you can use ``` align-item: center; ``` on the .anchorClass

Answer (score 1):

You could use Mubasher Ali's solution. Or you could make all anchors inside the anchorClass class block-level elements:

```css
.anchorClass a {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: If we would like to use horizontal align then what we can do ?

Comment: @user3283738 if you are using this solution then you can use ``` text-align: center; ``` and it will align the text inside the `a` tag not the element.

Answer (score -1):

no need for Flexbox here. The easiest method is to declare the anchors inside that container as block-level-elements with: `display: block`

```css
.anchorClass a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="anchorClass">
  <a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 1</a>
  <a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 2</a>
  <a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 3</a>
  <a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 4</a>
  <a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 5</a>
  <a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 6</a>
  <a href="xxxxxxxxx">Test 7</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `display:table` solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: what if he wanted to adjust their positions even more? like some center some at end and some at center?.
so just that's why he was using a wrapper around anchor tags. just give generic solution so that they can further expand it.

Comment: @MubasherAli but that was not asked...

Comment: @tacoshy yes but i think we should always give generic answer. as now he is asking to make it center horizontically.

Comment: @MubasherAli for which you also do not need flexbox... Flexbox is still not fully supported. You should always use the most simple solution with the best support before choosing to "advanced" methods

Comment: I would argue flexbox has good support these days. But display: block is simpler. And anyway you probably want block elements so height/width/margin and padding can be applied without issues.